# How can I run Genymotion with Lollipop and higher version on Ubuntu of 32-bit system?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I am using Genymotion on Ubuntu 32-bit system and I am able to start virtual device with version lower than Kitkat i.e. 4.4.4.

But I want to run virtual device with Lollipop and higher version.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting this error-
   (1)Unable to start the virtual device.
   (2)The virtual device got no IP address.
   (3)The VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the  
     virtual device. To find a solution, please start VirtualBox.

Comment: Do you have Vt-x enabled in your computer?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, but on Windows 10, 64-bit system

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit and unable to find Vt-x.

Comment: You have to go to your BIOS configuration and enable it.